# Do you use particular conventions for naming complementary variables?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions, variable-names

I often find myself trying to come up with good names for complementary pairs of variables; where two variables denote opposing concepts, two participants in some sort of duologue, and so on.

This might be better explained by a counter-example - I maintain an app that prints two graphics as part of a print advertisement. They're stored in the database as `TopLogo` and `LowerLogo`, which I have to stop and double-check every time I use them because I'm expecting `top` to complement `bottom`, and `lower` should complement `upper`.

There's some obvious examples that I think work well:

`client / server`
`source / target` for copying/moving data or files from one variable to another
`minimum / maximum`

but there's some concepts that just don't lend themselves to such neat naming schemes. For example, when paging through records, does 'last' mean 'final' or 'previous' ? I recently saw some  code that used `firstPage`, `previousPage`, `nextPage` and `finalPage` to avoid the ambiuous `lastPage` completely, which I thought was very beat, hence this question.

Do you have any particularly neat variable name pairs you'd care to share with us? (Bonus points if they're the same length, which makes the code so much neater in monospaced fonts.)

Comment: You've left out the most telling symptom of your compulsion... the complementary names must have the same number of letters. Come now, admit it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with all kinds of code style conventions, **consistency** is what you should strive for.
I would have the development team agree on "standard" pairs of prefixes for common scenarios like "source/destination"  or "from/to" and then stick with them for the whole project. As long as every developer is aware of what is meant with a particular prefix in the codebase, it is easier to avoid misunderstandings.
Exceptions to the rule should be clarified in the documentation if the variable is part of a public API, or in comments within the code, if it's visibility is restricted to a single class or method.

Answer (score 1):

While one does try to be semantically coherent in obvious cases -- e.g., maximum goes with minimum, and not "lowest" -- in well-structured OO code (which isn't all code, I know) the problem disappears with a good IDE. **Classes are short, methods are short, and variables are few in each method. So it doesn't matter what you call the variable pairs so long as they're clear. Your code might not look professional, but real quality is in the code, not in the *look* of your code.**

The problem further disappears if there is good JavaDoc or whatever the documentation system is, and if have good Class names that go with them. For instance, if you have an instance of a `Connection` class and it has a method a method called `setDestination`, that's okay, but if you know that setDestination takes one parameter called `destination` and it's of the `Server` class, you're cool... even though you might prefer to call it `target`, `aimHere`, `placeToSendTheData`, or `whatever` (and the corresponding names, `source`, `comingFromHere`, and `placeToGetTheDataFrom`). Plus the doc system says **what the thing is for**, and that is priceless.

This next thing might sound stupid and I'm sure I'll get voted down here on StackOverflow, but unique non-professional sounding variable names have a great advantage: I know that my variables have names like `placeWeWantTheDataToGo` (and the IDE takes care of typing it), but the "serious" guys who do the JDK would **never** use such silly names. So I know immediately that the variable is one of mine. Incidentally, when I worked with developers in Spain and Italy, they write code with Spanish variable names (not always, but usually). This causes the same effect: we can quickly see that the `Conexion` class is ours, but the `Connection` class is not.

[Also, instead of typing your variable names, assign them a constant String somewhere in your code and use that, so if they called it lower or downer instead of low, you're still okay.]

Answer (score 1):

In my databases you'll find many valid-state temporal ("history") tables containing a pair of columns named `start_date` and `end_date`. No bonus points for me, then, because I'd rather use the commonly used 'end' than try to come up with an intuitive alternative with the same number of characters as the word 'start'.

I tend to prefer these generic terms even when more context-specific terms may be viable e.g. preferring `employee_start_date` over `employee_hire_date` (what if their employment started for a reason other than being formally hiring e.g. their company was the subject of an acquisition). That said, I'd prefer `person_birth_date` over `person_start_date` :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do try to name complementary sets of variables systematically so that the symmetry is clear.  It is not always easy; sometimes, not even possible.  Well, not possible using the rules I lay down for myself - which means I usually try to have the names the same length.  The 'top' and 'lower' example would drive me batty (assuming I'm not batty already, which is far from certain); I'd probably use 'upper' and 'lower' because those are the same length; 'top' and 'bottom' would frustrate me too because of the difference in length.

Comment: yeah, it's top and bot if you want the same length :)